# Error in ng-route injectore:modulerr [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing, ngroute

i am trying to create a SPA(Single Page Application) with angular routing but when i add ndRoute to my module, it gives me this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=Dental&p1=Error%3A…tp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51792%2FDemoDental%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

this is my js code

```
(function(){
  var app= angular.module("Dental", ['ngRoute']);

app.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/aggrement', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/aggrement.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/home'
    });
}]);
})();
```

this is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="Dental">
<head>
  <title>DemoDental</title>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  </div>
  <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
  <div ng-view id="changeDiv"></div>
</div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i cant get the reason for this error as everything seems good to me ,
the programme run well if i remove ngRoute from my `angular.module()`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add angular route js file https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js

Answer (score 3):

add angular route

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: added this now it gives new erreo:Uncaught ReferenceError: $routeProvider is not defined